# Enable JSP Custom taglib to use spring service beans

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, autowired, taglib

I'm developing a web application using Spring MVC 3.2.4 (Spring Core 3.2.4 too) with jpa & hibernate for the back-end. And currently using Tomcat v6.0 for testing.

I had a case when i created a JSP custom tag lib (using jsp-api 2.1.1 & servlet-api 2.5), which is a custom lookups drop down list, i would give it the lookup type, and it would get from the DB the items under this type to render as items in the list.

The custom taglib class basically looks like something similar to this:

```
public class LookupsTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
  @Autowired
  private static LookupService lookupService;
  private String type;

    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        List<Lookup> items = lookupService.findByType(getType());

        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        buff.append("<select>");
        //...adding items...
        buff.append("</select>");
        getJspContext().getOut().write(buff.toString());
    }
  //getters and setters
}
```

And i have created the tld file accordingly and all.

Once i attempt to view a page using this custom tag, a **NullPointerException** is thrown because inside the *doTag()* method, the *lookupService* instance is *null*.

Spring doesn't seem to support custom jsp tags. Is there a way to work around this to make the service instance autowired automatically? Or am i missing some spring configurations to do?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your `LookupsTag` is defined as bean in spring configuration?

Comment: No, only the required configuration for any normal jsp taglib in a j2ee project.

Comment: LookupsTag is not, and never will be, a Spring managed bean. Anyway, what are you doing here? SpringMVC  already has tags which will do this for you: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select

Comment: Thanks Alan! I still don't have the deep technical knowledge on the offerings of spring-mvc. Looking at the documentation, this seems pretty sufficient!

Comment: You should add this as a solution, not comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alan Hay on his comment, custom jsp taglib will not be supported.
Spring is already providing what i needed through their taglib http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select